# log4j - why am I getting this ludicrous amount of DEBUG even if there's no log4j.properties?

Tags: log4j

I used to have the following file on `/src` but it didn't seem to be working. So I took it out (made sure to backup it first) and I am still getting a lot of debug info.
The file is:

```
# Log levels
# TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR

# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/home/gtl/workspace/hrm_agent/log/log.out
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=2MB

# Number of backup files
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10

# Layout for Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this file in your classpath?

Comment: Well, isn't `/src` part of the classpath by default? If not, how do I make it so?

Comment: try running with vm argument -cp {blah}/src

Comment: @SMA, All is OK now! Thanks!